# Proving combinatoric identity

Tags: combinatorics

I am struggling with this identity :

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n+1}{k}=2^{2n}$$

Thanks for your help

Comment: This is also an algebraic identity, so you might try and prove it algebraically, if so a hint is the binomial theorem. If you want a combinatoric proof however, try and work out what each side is counting.

Comment: Notice that the expression on the LHS counts the number of subsets containing fewer than half the elements of a set with an odd number of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$S=\sum_{k=0}^{n} {2n+1 \choose k}.$$
By binomial expansion
$$(1+1)^{2n+1}=\sum_{j=0}^{n} {2n+1 \choose k}=1+{2n+1 \choose 1}+{2n+1 \choose 2}+{2n+1 \choose 3}+......+{2n+1 \choose n}+ {2n+1 \choose n+1}+{2n+1 \choose n+2}+.....+{2n+1 \choose 2n+1}=2^{2n+1}$$
Using the redlection propert of binomial cofficientafter $(n+1)$th term, we get
$$(1+1)^{2n+1}=\sum_{j=0}^{n} {2n+1 \choose k}=1+{2n+1 \choose 1}+{2n+1 \choose 2}+{2n+1 \choose 3}+......+{2n+1 \choose n}+ {2n+1 \choose n-1}+{2n+1 \choose n-2}+.....+{2n+1 \choose 0}=2^{2n+1}$$
$$\implies 2S=2^{2n+1}\implies S=2^{2n}$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the expansion of the binomial
$$(x+1)^{2n+1}$$
And subsitute $x = 1$